# displaying webview via proxy server

Tags: android

I have a problem with the display of my webview, when I pass a url directly, it displays normally without problems. BUT when the url connects to the proxy server requesting the web page, my page does not display well (it does not adjust the size of the emulator screen and I see that the left corner of the top) and I have no scroll bar to scroll the contents of the page.
have you an idea on this
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device?